# Incompatible shared library

Tags: python, shared

One of my application use shared library ABC.so which is generated by python 3.4 but rest of the application must use python 3.6 for some reason. Now the library is incompatible, I can't run my application. I also do not have source code for ABC.so. is there a way to fix or upgrade the library?